# jQuery send data to php file and then back again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, client

i have a problem with sending data to a php file and then back again (with jQuery).

I know the `$.post` -> `.done` function.

My jQuery looks like:

```
$.post("client.php", { 
    request: request 
})
 .done(function( data ) {
     $("#requestdiv").html(data);
 });
```

The client.php connects to a server, the server returns a unique number to the client(1). 
After this (and this is the Problem) the `client.php` file is loading as long as another client submits the request or server close connection.

But client 1 needs the unique number. Because the person from client 1 tells the person from client 2 (by word of mouth) the unique number and client 2 submit the unique number to the server. After this the server answers client1 and client2, close the connection and the file finishes loading.

The `post` to `client.php` works fine. My problem is how can i receive the data although the file did not finish loading (because the client - server connection is still open)?

Thanks for helping..

**Update:**

The `read()` method from `client.php`.

```
    while ($data = socket_read($this->m_sock, $length, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) {
       if ($data) {
          if (strpos($data, "\n", $start) != false) {
            $end = strpos($data, "\n", $start);
            $result = substr($data, $start, $end);
            $this->onCommandLine($result);
          }
      } else {
          break;
      }
    }
```

This method is loading as long as the server close the connection. Because of this, the jQuery do not get a result in `data`. The server closes the connection after the transaction has finished.

Comment: Can you post your client.php code?

Comment: I don't really know if there is a better way, but what I would do is to send the first request with the desired data and close. PHP will process server-side then store the result(json?) anywhere(e.g. temporary txt). Then send a new request in an interval until get that temporary data.

Comment: in an interval you mean to check all (for example) 10 seconds if the temporary txt exists? I also can make a database.